# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException during server-side debug

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, partial-postback

Often during debug of server-side VB.NET/C# code that is executed inside of ASP.NET partial postack (UpdatePanel, other controls with AJAX behaviors) I am getting this client-side error:

[image: Debug error]

At this point I do not care about client-side (and at runtime this is not happening). It's just a major annoyance during debug - is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET UpdatePanel Time Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158975/asp-net-updatepanel-time-out)

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you have an ASP ScriptManager for AJAX processing.   That control has a default Async PostBack timeout of 90 seconds, after which it will throw this exception.

The solution is rather simple:   Add an ASP tag during debug to extend the timeout for as long as a debug session might take you:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="3600">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The above will let me run a debug session for one hour before throwing that exception.  Don't forget to remove that tag for your production releases, or a hung loop etc, will never time out.

Jeff