# ASP.NET page stops processing after 30 seconds

Tags: asp.net, timeout

I have this ASP.NET application that works fine. One of the pages packages a large amount of data for download, which sometimes takes a few minutes. On my development machine, when debugging, it works fine. But on the production machine, the page stops processing after approximately 30 seconds. The user experience in production is this:

1. The user navigates to this page.
2. The user clicks on a button to download the large file.
3. The browser displays the usual "processing" icon on the page tab, indicating the request is being served.
4. After 30 seconds, the browser removes the "processing" icon and goes back to the regular tab icon. Nothing else happens.

In development (debug) mode, the page keeps processing after 3 and, eventually, the file is offered for download, as expected.

Something must be interrupting the processing after 30 seconds. I have tried setting all the properties I know of, including `Server.ScriptTimeout` in code and `executionTimeout` on `web.config`, but the result doesn't change.

What other settings may be related to this? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide screenshot from the browser network result after the processing icon disappears ?

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158975/asp-net-updatepanel-time-out)